# BigQuery: Invalid table ID

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert a row using this example code:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples

I'm receiving an error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid table ID \"projectid:datasetid.tableid\".",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid table ID \"projectid:datasetid.tableid\"."
}
```

The project, dataset and table all exist. When I copy the actual projectid:datasetid.tableid from the error report and paste it into the BigQuery web UI, it works. The projectid has a '-' in it, the rest is alphanumeric. Why would the API complain about an id that the web UI accepts?

---

Update to answer Jordan's question. This is my call:

```
TableDataInsertAllResponse response =
    bigquery
    .tabledata()
    .insertAll(projectId, datasetId, table.getId(), content)
    .execute();
```

Before I call this, I ensure the project, dataset and table all exist by getting them. I then use the table's actual id.

---

New information: turns out (as you suspected) the table.getId() returns the fully qualified id, including project and dataset. When I hardcode the shortened id to exclude them, it worked.

Comment: It sounds like you're sending a single name as the table name rather than splitting it up into components. If that isn't the case, can you send the actual code you are calling?

Comment: Hi Jordan. Updated. (Btw, thanks for the effort you guys put into SO.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha... ok this is expected. The `table.getId()` call is going to return the fully-qualified name of the table (i.e. project:dataset.table).  (see  https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables).

Try `table.getTableReference().getTableId()` instead. (see https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/Table.html#getTableReference())

Why, you may ask? Every REST resource is supposed to have a unique id. The table's fully-qualified unique ID is the project:dataset.table name. However, when you are passing the components of the id, the table component is just the last part of that name.