# Bigquery "Getting IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Table ID" error while reading part of bigquery table into pyspark dataframe using query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, azure-databricks

I am trying to read a section of bigquery table using query in azure databricks spark.

```
table_id = str(project_id) + "." + str(schema) + "." + str(table_name)
```

I am able to read complete table data using the following query.

```
 _data = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentials", ans). \
     option("parentProject", project_id). \
     option("project", project_id). \
     option("table", table_id). \
     option("dataset", schema).load()
```

But when i try to do the same using sql query in the following way,

```
_query = """select * from `{}` limit 2""".format(table_id)
_data = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentials", ans). \
    option("parentProject", project_id). \
    option("project", project_id). \
    option("dataset", schema). \
    load(_query)

total = _data.count()
```

> IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Table ID 'select
> col1 from `proj-164408.schema.mytable` limit 2'.
> Must match '^(((\S+)[:.])?(\w+).)?([\S&&[^.:]]+)$$'

I tried with differnt types of table ids like
**proj-164408:schema.mytable** , **proj-164408:schema:mytable**

Attaching the stacktrace information.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-755248569207678> in <module>
     88     option("parentProject", project_id). \
     89     option("project", project_id).option("dataset", schema). \
---> 90     load(_query)
     91 
     92 total = _data.count()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    176         self.options(**options)
    177         if isinstance(path, basestring):
--> 178             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    179         elif path is not None:
    180             if type(path) != list:

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    131                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    132                 # JVM exception message.
--> 133                 raise_from(converted)
    134             else:
    135                 raise

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in raise_from(e)
```

*Databricks Run time version that i used: 7.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)*

There is already a question which talks about similar issue but could not apply that to my case.
Refer [BigQuery: Invalid table ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102896/bigquery-invalid-table-id)

**Update 1:**

Found one link for source code which throws the mentioned error.
[com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryUtil](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/master/connector/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/connector/common/BigQueryUtil.java) Line number: 106

It seems we can only give fully qualified table name,

```java
      private static final String PROJECT_PATTERN = "\\S+";
      private static final String DATASET_PATTERN = "\\w+";
      // Allow all non-whitespace beside ':' and '.'.
      // These confuse the qualified table parsing.
      private static final String TABLE_PATTERN = "[\\S&&[^.:]]+";
      /**
       * Regex for an optionally fully qualified table.
       *
       * <p>Must match 'project.dataset.table' OR the legacy 'project:dataset.table' OR 'dataset.table'
       * OR 'table'.
       */
      private static final Pattern QUALIFIED_TABLE_REGEX =
          Pattern.compile(
              format("^(((%s)[:.])?(%s)\\.)?(%s)$$", PROJECT_PATTERN, DATASET_PATTERN, TABLE_PATTERN));

    Matcher matcher = QUALIFIED_TABLE_REGEX.matcher(rawTable);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          format("Invalid Table ID '%s'. Must match '%s'", rawTable, QUALIFIED_TABLE_REGEX));
```

Since i gave SQL query instead of fq table name, i am getting mentioned error.

Comment: I think the problem is you use the full path to the table but still set project id and dataset. I'm not familiar with pyspark, but you can try use project id and dataset once instead of in both path and option parameters.

Comment: @KaBoom I tried without them also. Still the error is same.

IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Table ID 'select col1 from `proj-164408.schema.mytable` limit 2'. Must match '^(((\S+)[:.])?(\w+).)?([\S&&[^.:]]+)$$'

Comment: Have you fixed this? I just had your exactly same error...

Comment: @SkyOne We had a workaround. I have added that as answer. Check it out. It may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, we are using big query client along with spark to read the section of dataframe.

```
import json
import base64 as bs
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import bigquery

project_id = ""
schema = ""
table_name = ""
credentials_dict = {}

schema_table_name = str(project_id) + "." + str(schema) + "." + str(table_name)
s = json.dumps(credentials_dict)
res = bs.b64encode(s.encode('utf-8'))
ans = res.decode("utf-8")
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_dict)

query = "SELECT * FROM `{}` where col_1 > 50;".format(schema_table_name)

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id)
query_job = client.query(query)
query_job.result()

df = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
    .option("credentials", ans) \
    .option("parentProject", project_id) \
    .option("project", project_id) \
    .option('dataset', query_job.destination.dataset_id) \
    .load(query_job.destination.table_id)
```